# if statement in lambda Scheme

Tags: if-statement, lambda, scheme

I'm a new schemer. I just want to ask if I can include if-statements in a lambda? For example, (lambda (x) (if e1 e2 e3)). I don't see why not, but my program just keep failing if I write this way.

Thanks a lot!

Here's my code here.I'm trying to implement filter with higher-order functions as an exercise. Since @sepp2k has answered that it's totally fine to include ifs in lambda, I'd guess it's the problem of my use of foldr?

If anyone can give some insight into this to help me understand the way it works, I'd really appreciate it!

```
(define filter (f xs)
  (if (null? xs) '()
     (foldr (lambda (elem ys) ((if (f elem) (cons elem ys)
                                   (cons '() ys)))) '() xs)))
```

Comment: Please edit the question text to include the non-working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course we can use an `if` inside a `lambda`, in fact, any valid expression can go inside a `lambda`. There are more serious errors in your code:

1. There are additional (and unnecessary) parentheses surrounding the innermost `if` expression. Scheme will interpret them as a function application, and that's not what you want to do here
2. The `else` of the `if` expression is wrong, you just have to pass the accumulator without modifications
3. The function definition is incorrect

Also the whole function can be simplified, there's no need for the outermost `if` and the indentation can be improved. Try this:

```
(define (filter f xs)
  (foldr (lambda (elem ys)
           (if (f elem)       ; if the predicate is true
               (cons elem ys) ; then `cons` element to accumulator
               ys))           ; otherwise leave accumulator alone
         '()
         xs))
```

It works as expected:

```
(filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '(2 4 6)
```

Comment: How careless I'm!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to use ifs inside lambdas. If your program fails that must be because of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Extra parens around the call to `if`. Scheme overloads grouping `(list of expressions)` and function-calls `(+ 2 2)`.
FWIW, you might also use `foldl`, as `foldr` takes up `O(|elements of the input|)` memory.

Going deeper, lambdas are what's called a "special form" in scheme. That means that they obey different evaluation rules. I only bring this up because it gives some insight into a key feature of scheme: everything is just a form. `define`? Special form. `lambda`? Special form. Nothing you couldn't write yourself if you really felt like it. That means that with a lot of special forms, even if they seem automagic/baked-in, they don't have any esoteric caveats lying around.

Also, just for future reference, here are a couple of gems for your scheming: [MIT Scheme Reference (lambdas)](http://sicp.ai.mit.edu/Fall-2003/manuals/scheme-7.5.5/doc/scheme_3.html), [Racket Guide (Pairs and Lists)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29)